# Graphlab and SFrame

Tags: python, attributes, graphlab, sframe

I am taking a course on Machine Learning in which GraphLab and SFrame are being used for data manipulation and loading. When I try to load data using SFrame then I get this error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 sf = graphlab.SFrame('people-example.csv')
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SFrame'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: It's not possible to help you fix your code if you don't share the code with us. It's like asking a mechanic to repair your car without giving him the car.